# .val(this.value); minus 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, hotkeys

I have few tabs with input on each tab. I am using and I set on each input the same class so I can carry the value from one tab to another, like this:

```
$('.group_input1').change(function(){
     $('.group_input1').val(this.value);
});
```

Now, to show each tab I am using shortkeys like this:

```
if (e.keyCode == 71) {
        $("#input1").fadeIn();
    $(".group_input").focus();
    }
```

Each time the #input1 fade's In its input gets a value of the character pressed, so I am looking for something to say, when `$(".group_input").focus();` delete last character ?

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Define "tabs", because you're not using jQuery tabs.

Comment: That is not my question sir. My question is, how do I remove one character on .val(this.value);

Comment: @jQuerybeast see [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) link for future reference.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Huh? I know what your question is. Now I'm asking _you_ one: what do you mean by "tabs"? How did you implement them?

Comment: I've set on each tab the class="tabs" and on each keydown I call $('.tabs:not(#input1)').hide(); ...

Comment: Ok I've found the answer. I changed from keydown to keyup. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. For the shortkeys I was using keydown instead of keyup, so I replaced it

Answer (score 0):

Something like (code not tested) -

```
$('#target').focus(function() {
  $("#input1").val($("#input1").val().substring(0,$("#input1").val().length-1))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you can use the "substring" function to remove the last character from the string e.g.

```
var text = "input1";
var text_new = text.substring(0, text.length-1);
alert(text_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the last character you could do:

```
$(".group_input").focus(function(){
    var valore =  $(this).val();
    $(this).val(valore.substring(0, valore.length - 1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see more of the code to understand why the key is being added to that input. Is the e.keyCode portion within a keydown event?

As a simple solution just to get something that works you could set up a focus event handler on group_input to remove that character (see below), but I doubt it's the ideal way to do it. You should instead block that key from being added to the text. Can you set up an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

```
$('.group_input').focus(function () {
    var text = $('#input1').val();
    $('#input1').val(text.substr(0, text.length - 1));
}
```

Comment: One minute, I'll make you a fiddle because the -1 text.length it doesn't seem to be an answer to this.

Comment: Can you check this sir? http://jsfiddle.net/fSRHS/ Note: When you press the letter 'g', the input fade's in with the letter g but only the first time.

Comment: Ok I've found the answer. I changed from keydown to keyup. Thanks alot

Comment: I think the length-1 wasn't working because it was calling focus from within the keydown event. That way it runs and completes while before the 'g' is actually entered. I like the keyup method -- seems to work pretty well. [Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSRHS/1/) in case anybody needs it.